# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build an image classification model that can recognize if you are wearing a mask and I got a problem when training a model.

```
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

This is my code

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
import os
import cv2
import random

def getData():
     training = []

     for image in os.listdir("src/data/with_mask"):
          img = cv2.imread(f"src/data/with_mask/{image}",0)
          training.append([img.tolist(),1])

     for image in os.listdir("src/data/without_mask"):
          img = cv2.imread(f"src/data/without_mask/{image}",0)
          training.append([img.tolist(),0])

     random.shuffle(training)
     train_x = np.array([x[0] for x in training])
     train_y = np.array([x[1] for x in training])
     return (train_x ,train_y)


train_x , train_y = getData()

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(128,input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),),activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="softmax"))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])



hist = model.fit(
    train_x,train_y,
    epochs=100, batch_size=8, verbose=1)
model.save("model.h5", hist)
```

I've tried changing `np.array([...])` to `np.array([...],dtype=np.float32)` but then i get error
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

My training data shape is

```
[[[
 [...]
 [...]
 [...]
 [...]
],1],...]
```

I will be very thankful if someone post answer below.

Comment: when you are converting items into numpy array the items in the array are still list, please try to print your train_x and train_y and see whether it contains a list in it

Comment: only rectangular shaped things can be fully converted into numpy array like `np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2]])` -> this cannot be fully converted into numpy array whereas `np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]])` will

Comment: But i should print them before or after converting into numpy array

Comment: its all upto you, you can print both and see for the same xD

Comment: i printed the shape of the train_x and train_y and iv got the following:```(7553,)(7553,)```

Comment: did you try printing the train_x itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solve it thanks to @SanchritJain the problem was that I wasn't resizing the images.